# Longer time to shutdown Tomcat JVM Service after 64bit upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, 64-bit, shutdown

I have a windows 2012 based server running Tomcat 8 and Java 7 instances as windows service using wrapper.exe.

After I migrated my services to 64bit JVM, my service shutdown is taking time longer then usual, earlier the shutdown time was around 8-10 seconds which now goes upto 1 min.

Here are the threads which still seems to be alive after 10 seconds when I triggered the process shutdown. Please let me know what really could trigger this.

```
13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.404 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7000"]
13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.482 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7443"]
13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.545 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-7009"]
13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.607 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina

13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [Server: Logger Manager] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
com.MyCom.server.logger.LoggerManager.run(LoggerManager.java:193)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [DiskWriteThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
com.MyCom.server.logger.CacheToDiskWriter.run(CacheToDiskWriter.java:62)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [LogManagerMonitor thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
com.MyCom.server.logger.LogManagerMonitor.run(LogManagerMonitor.java:43)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [SNMPForwarderHBSendThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
snmp.SNMPForwarderHBSendThread._sleep(SNMPForwarderHBSendThread.java:68)
snmp.SNMPForwarderHBSendThread.run(SNMPForwarderHBSendThread.java:55)

13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [SNMPForwarderHBDeathClock] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
snmp.SNMPForwarderHBDeathClock._sleep(SNMPForwarderHBDeathClock.java:75)
snmp.SNMPForwarderHBDeathClock.run(SNMPForwarderHBDeathClock.java:62)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [SNMPForwarderReceiveThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData(Native Method)
java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:121)
java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:145)
java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:786)
snmp.SNMPForwarderReceiveThread.run(SNMPForwarderReceiveThread.java:74)

13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [SNMPForwarderConnectionEstablisherThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
snmp.SNMPForwarderConnectionEstablisherThread._sleep(SNMPForwarderConnectionEstablisherThread.java:244)
snmp.SNMPForwarderConnectionEstablisherThread.run(SNMPForwarderConnectionEstablisherThread.java:223)

13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [Log Purge Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [Server: License Expiration Checker] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
com.MyCom.server.licensing.VXMLLicenseExpirationChecker.run(VXMLLicenseExpirationChecker.java:71)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [Transport-reader-group-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
queue.LinkedMessageQueue.dequeue(LinkedMessageQueue.java:139)
queue.TransportMessageReaderWorker.singlePoll(TransportMessageReaderWorker.java:133)
queue.TransportMessageReaderWorker.run(TransportMessageReaderWorker.java:48)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:622)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:310)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:110)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [Global-task-executor-group-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1079)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [IvrProvider-writer-group-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
queue.LinkedMessageQueue.dequeue(LinkedMessageQueue.java:139)
queue.TransportMessageWriterWorker.singlePoll(TransportMessageWriterWorker.java:96)
queue.TransportMessageWriterWorker.run(TransportMessageWriterWorker.java:53)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [StatsIntervalThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
statistics.StatsIntervalThread._sleep(StatsIntervalThread.java:95)
statistics.StatsIntervalThread.run(StatsIntervalThread.java:56)

13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [SNMPStatsThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
statistics.SNMPStatsThread._sleep(SNMPStatsThread.java:54)
statistics.SNMPStatsThread.run(SNMPStatsThread.java:35)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [StatsLoggerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
statistics.StatsLoggerThread._sleep(StatsLoggerThread.java:48)
statistics.StatsLoggerThread.run(StatsLoggerThread.java:31)


13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.623 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2]
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CVP] appears to have started a thread named [LoggerManagerWorker] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
com.MyCom.server.util.BoundedLinkedQueue.poll(BoundedLinkedQueue.java:303)
com.MyCom.server.util.ThreadPool.getTask(ThreadPool.java:737)
com.MyCom.server.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:773)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.639 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7000"]
13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.639 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7443"]
13-Dec-2015 17:12:37.639 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-7009"]
```

Comment: Thanks cadrian for rearranging logs.

Comment: are the 32bit and 64bit instances configured with the same GC settings/heap constraints etc?

Comment: The heap size is increased to 2 GB from 1 GB in 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I see some thread pools in your log. Unless provided with a factory that creates daemon threads they will create non-daemon ones by default. The JVM does not terminate until all non-daemon threads have terminated.

So my guess is that the JVM is held alive by thread pools that are not shut down properly and instead cull their threads when they GCed and finalized.

Finalization is dependent on GC pressure. As you changed the heap limit that may have made GCs less frequent and thus delays the shutdown.

Of course that's a fairly long chain of potential causes, so it's little more than a guess.